# Two commands in one line

Tags: bash, cut, free-command

Why is it that:

```
free | cut -c67- && free | cut -c55-61
```

gives me buffer and cache size, but

```
free -s4 | cut -c67- && free -s4 | cut -c55-61
```

gives me only the cache size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Bash man page:

> ```
> SHELL GRAMMA
>    [...]
>    Lists
>         AND and OR lists are sequences of one of more pipelines separated by the && and || control operators,  respec‐
>         tively.  AND and OR lists are executed with left associativity.  An AND list has the form
>
>             command1 && command2
>
>         command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.
> ```

the `&&` operator won't execute command2 until command1 exited with return value 0.

Is command `free -s4 | cut -c67-,56-61` more close to what you want?